# Audio.play() on React gives error DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html5-audio

When I run `playAudio1()` it doesn't play the sound, but `playAudio2()` does. I have hundreds of audio files in the folder. That is why I use `require.context()` since I cannot import each single one manually. Any thoughts on how I can make this work?

```
import React from 'react';
import Volume from '../../../../images/audio.png';
import Song from '../../../../audio/ES/banana.mp3';
const audio = require.context("../../../../audio/ES", true);

const ScreenKids = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <img src={Volume} onClick={() => playAudio1()} />
                <img src={Volume} onClick={() => playAudio2()} />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

function playAudio1() {
    new Audio(audio('./banana.mp3')).play();
}

function playAudio2() {
    new Audio(Song).play();
}

export default ScreenKids;
```

When I run audio.keys() as suggested by @bogdanoff I get the below result:

```
(224) ['./ambulance.mp3', …, './banana.mp3', …]
```

Comment: where are the mp3 files located in folder, may be adding your folder structure (an image should be fine ) helps ...

Comment: run this code & attach result to post, `console.log(audio.keys())`

Comment: good, seems right. I tried this on my project & its working. Code is almost same as yours and no errors were thrown just there was slight delay in playing music thats it. I am not sure what happening may be restart dev server ?.

Comment: Thanks for trying! I tried to restart the dev server, delete the build and node_modules folders and run npm install and npm run build but still the same result. I have read that it might be a CORS issue but not sure how to resolve it.

Comment: I guess that `./banana.mp3` is not a valid path

Comment: @KonradLinkowski it is. When the path or filename are wrong I get a different error. I guess this is a config issue related to CORS.

Comment: So maybe the audio didn't load yet. You can add `onload` event.
`const audio = new Audio(Song); audio.onload = () => audio.play()`

Comment: @KonradLinkowski Interesting. When I run your code I see the code inside the onload() is never executed. The DOMException consequently disappears. Still no sound played.

Comment: You can also add `onerror` handler to see if it gets any errors

Comment: The error is MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED. I can play the file manually with no problem. Same issue happens if I try to play a .wav file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of debugging I was able to fix this by upgrading package `react-scripts` from `"4.0.2"` to `"^5.0.1"`.